# Scheduled Job via Apex in PostInstall Class - Can we set the user?

Tags: apex, managed-package, postinstall

When adding a schedule job via Apex in the PostInstall class of a package (via System.schedule), the job gets submitted by the package (ghost user), not a user in SFDC. Is there a way to specify which user it should run as? Maybe the installation user?

Or even a way to change the running user?

Basically, we are seeing issues where "Last Modified" shows a blank user which causes errors on page layouts (related record components).

Comment: You could consider using a custom `Platform Event` with a specified user. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm

Comment: If scheduled directly the user will always be the "ghost user" - and this causes all sorts of problems (as both you and we have found). The biggest problem you have in setting the specified user for the platform event subscriber metadata, as suggested by @AdrianLarson, is that you can only create this metadata with existing user IDs which, of course, won't exist when installing the package. Basically you'll have to add a post install page (if VF you can set this in the package metadata) that the admin visits to press a button to schedule the job.

Comment: That said, if you use a Platform Event without trying to specifically set the user, it will at least run as the Automated Process user...